# Как получить данные пользовательского слоя?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Всем добра!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли скачать данные пользовательского слоя карты в каком-нибудь "невизуальном" виде? Т.е., например, имея ссылку вида [https://yandex.ru/maps/?l=sat%2Cskl&mode=usermaps&source=constructorLink&um=constructor%3Сxxxxx](https://yandex.ru/maps/?l=sat%2Cskl&mode=usermaps&source=constructorLink&um=constructor%3%D0%A1xxxxx) получить txt/json/kml/whatever c координатами нарисованных на карте полигонов (и размещённых объектов)?

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс старается оградить пользователей, создающих карты в [Конструкторе](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) от подобных краж результата их труда. Потому методов, позволяющих получить объекты пользовательских карт сторонним пользователям нет - только просмотр в интерфейсе.